# Non Divisible subset in python

Tags: python

I have been given a set S, of n integers, and have to print the size of a maximal subset S' of S where the sum of any 2 numbers in S' are not evenly divisible by k.

**Input Format**

The first line contains 2 space-separated integers, n and k, respectively. 
The second line contains n space-separated integers describing the unique values of the set.

**My Code :**

```
import sys


n,k = raw_input().strip().split(' ')
n,k = [int(n),int(k)]
a = map(int,raw_input().strip().split(' '))
count = 0


for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        if (a[i]+a[j])%k != 0:
            count = count+1

print count
```

**Input:**

```
4 3
1 7 2 4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
3
```

**My Output:**

```
10
```

What am i doing wrong? Anyone?

Comment: Your code does something entirely unrelated to the problem. It's not a matter of some minor detail you're doing wrong.

Comment: @C14L: How many elements of S can you pick without picking two elements that add up to a multiple of k?

Comment: @user2357112 Then how about `len([x for x in itertools.combinations(a, 2) if operator.add(*x) % k])`?

Comment: @C14L: You're still solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @user2357112 I am getting the right solution. And non of the remaining items `[(1, 7), (1, 4), (7, 4)]` can be combined into a divisible by `k`.

Comment: This is a [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w20/challenges/non-divisible-subset) from an ongoing contest on hackerrank. Wait till it finishes and you'll be aple to see the solutions.

Comment: @C14L: You're only getting the right number by coincidence; the number of pairs with sum not divisible by 3 and the size of the maximal subset happen to be equal for this input. (The maximal subset is `{1, 4, 7}`.)

Comment: @eugeney Thanks for the link. I get a 404 though and Goog finds nothing. I guess, I'd need to register to see the problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# given k, n and a as per your input.
# Will return 0 directly if n == 1
def maxsize(k, n, a):
    import itertools
    while n > 1:
        sets = itertools.combinations(a, n)
        for set_ in sets:
            if all((u+v) % k for (u, v) in itertools.combinations(set_, 2)):
                return n
        n -= 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Exponential time, but at least it usually gives the right answer. `return 0` is the wrong value to fall back on, though. It's only right for n=0. When the input has at least one element, we can always pick a valid 1-element subset.

Comment: Yes. Exponential time. Are you expecting I break NP set? Pay me $1000000 (the CMI prize) and I will try XDDDD

Comment: You don't need to solve P/NP to do this in linear time. There's a fairly straightforward solution based on deciding whether to allow residue `x` or `k-x` in your set for each possible `x`, with special cases for residue `0` or `k/2`.

Comment: Post it as an answer and have my upvote ;). I am too dumb today.

Answer (score 16):

You can solve it in `O(n)` time using the following approach:

```
L = [0]*k

for x in a: 
    L[x % k] += 1
res = 0
for i in range(k//2+1):
    if i == 0 or k == i*2:
        res += bool(L[i])
    else:
        res += max(L[i], L[k-i])

print(res)
```

Comment: This is a really awesome answer, more in-depth explanation of this algorithm: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57873/maximum-subset-pairwise-not-divisible-by-k

Comment: bro.. what does this line means? `res += bool(L[i])`

Comment: Increment `res` if `L[i]` is "true" (non-zero)

Comment: @planetp, it is similar to `!L[i].nil?` in ruby

Comment: what does k//2+1 mean?. I know of k/2+1,k+=1k-=1,etc. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Eswar `//` means floor divide, which is to divide and then round down. 3 / 2 = 1.5, 3 // 2 = 1

Answer (score 2):

Yes O(n) solution for this problem is very much possible. Like planetp rightly pointed out its pretty much the same solution I have coded in java. Added comments for better understanding.

> import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
>
> public class Solution {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>     int n=in.nextInt();
>     int k=in.nextInt();
>     int [] arr = new int[k];
>     Arrays.fill(arr, 0);
>     Map<Integer,Integer> mp=new HashMap<>();
> ```
>
> Storing the values in a map considering there are no duplicates. You can store them in array list if there are duplicates. Only then you have different results.
>           for(int i=0;i

```
    int res=0;

    for(int i=0;i<=(k/2);i++)
    {
        if(i==0 || k==i*2)
        {
            if(arr[i]!=0)
               res+=1;
        }
```

If the no. is divisible by k we can have only one and if the no is exactly half of k then we can have only 1. Rational if a & b are divisble by k then a+b is also divisible by k. Similarly if c%k=k/2 then if we have more than one such no. their combination is divisible by k. Hence we restrict them to 1 value each.
            else
            {
                int p=arr[i];
                int q=arr[k-i];
                if(p>=q)
                    res+=p;
                else
                    res+=q;
            }

This is simple figure out which is more from a list of 0 to k/2 in the list if a[x]>a[k-x] get the values which is greater. i.e. if we have k=4 and we have no. 1,3,5,7,9,13,17. Then a[1]=4 and a[3]=2 thus pick a[1] because 1,5,13,17 can be kept together.

```
    }   
       System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to store values, I would use HashSet, not a Map

Answer (score 0):

Java solution

```
public class Solution {

    static PrintStream out = System.out;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int k = in.nextInt();        
        int[] A = new int[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            A[i]=in.nextInt();
        }

        int[] R = new int[k];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)            
            R[A[i] % k]+=1;

        int res=0;
        for(int i=0;i<k/2+1;i++){
            if(i==0 || k==i*2)
                res+= (R[i]!=0)?1:0;
            else
                res+= Math.max(R[i], R[k-i]);            
        }

        out.println(res);
    }
}
```